# Reduce the size of the image android

Tags: android, image

How can i reduce the size of the image android programatically.

Size of image can be set in grid view. Is it possible to set the size of image displayed in 
Edit Text that is received from grid view selected image.

I have set of images in my gridview. I can reduce the size of the image in grid view display. so when i selct the image in gridview i get the image in edittext with its original size of image bigger. How can i reduce the size to small image.

Please guide me in this issue. Any sample working example shall be very useful for me to understand and work accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try something like this,

[Reduce Image Size](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html)