# How to update first and second page view in view pager.?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

I have View-pager with nine images. I am setting images in view using bitmap. When i choose nine images from gallery first time, its show all nine images perfectly. Also when i choose another nine images from gallery with keep first first or second view same,view-pager display with updated images. But my problem is when I am trying to change all nine images with first and second. they display error like `OutOfMemoryEror`. so my question is. How to update first and second(next) view in view-pager.  any one can help me.? than x in advance.

**Activity code**

```
if(ab != null){

      arr = ab.split(",");        

      for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){                     
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done: "+ arr[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        imgFile = new  File(arr[i]);
        if(imgFile.exists()){
           myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());             

            System.out.println("This my - bit : "+myBitmap+"ara - lenth : "+arr.length);

            bitmapArray.add(myBitmap);

            System.out.println("This bit-aray : "+bitmapArray.size()+" : "+bitmapArray.size() + "ara pos : "+arr[i]);

      //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is bitmap array : "+ bitmapArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }

            }
    }else{

    }
```

**Adapter code**

```
if(l == 1){
//  layout.removeView(imageView); 
//  container.removeView(layout);
  if(bitmapArray != null){

     for(int j = 0; j < bitmapArray.size(); j++){

         if(j == position){

                j = position;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(j));
            }
     }
     }   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+bitmapArray.get(j)+"size "+bitmapArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 else{
     imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
     bitarray.clear();
     bitmapArray.clear();
     sharedpreferences.edit().remove("imgpath").commit();
     }
   }
 if(l == 2){

//layout.removeView(imageView); 
//container.removeView(layout);

  if(bitmapArray != null){

         for(int j = 0; j < bitmapArray.size(); j++){

             if(j == position){

                    j = position;
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(j));
                }
         }
         }   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+bitmapArray.get(j)+"size "+bitmapArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     else{
         imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
         bitarray.clear();
         bitmapArray.clear();
         sharedpreferences.edit().remove("imgpath").commit();
     }

 }
```

Comment: finally, I have found that, its occur due to large image size. when I add small size image it work perfect, but when I add large image it so error like  ` outOfMemory`.

Comment: Now any one have idea, How can I reduce size of image befor add in view-pager.?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565931/reduce-the-size-of-the-image-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510166/how-to-reduce-image-programmatically-in-android